# How to get rid of browser alert message "Open Microsoft Edge ?" while trying to open a URL in edge browser from a react application running in chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, url, window, microsoft-edge

I am trying to open a URL inside Edge browser from a react application running in chrome like below

`window.open('microsoft-edge:https://www.cnn.com')`

Chrome is throwing an alert like below...

[image]

Checking the always allow checkbox might solve the issue, but is it possible to disable this behavior using JavaScript ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you cannot control this behavior using JavaScript, as this is a security approach to warn users of such a redirection behavior.

In short, user gesture (interaction with the prompt) is required in the redirection via web-based protocols. So far, ticking the checkbox seems to be the best solution.